# Unable to get fb comments owner profile

Tags: node.js, facebook

I am trying to access profile of a user like `username`, `user id` who send comments on Facebook pages and posts. I am using Facebook comment API to access comments from Facebook  page. Response I got from API does not contain user information for third party comment.

```
    {
        "created_time": "2020-01-30T11:27:22+0000",
        "message": "Hello whats up",
        "id": "123421204391473_126608478686089"
    }
```

How can I get user information?

Comment: how do you access the data? are you using a page token of the page in question? ist the app public? or are you using an app token and you applied for page public content access?

Comment: I am using page access token to access comments